# How to use message queues when working with parallel processes in php?

Tags: php, message-queue

I'm trying to implement a program where a parent process opens multiple child processes (usually around 40) that run in parallel to each other.

Now, I want to be able to get the child processes talking to the parent process to extract some information that only the parent process has. My plan was to use [message queues in php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.msg-send.php) but I'm running into some issues. Here is my basic design:

1. Parent process starts
2. Parent process opens multiple child processes
3. Each child process sends multiple messages to the parent process. For example a particular child can send anywhere from 20 to 100 messages to the parent.
4. Parent receives each messages and sends a 'return' message to the child, for each message that the parent receives
5. Child receives the replies from the parent and performs some action

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to get this to work. I've tried many different things such as have a separate queue for each child, which gave me a "Warning: msg_get_queue() [function.msg-get-queue]: failed for key  No space left on device in ..." even though I was deleting the queues after I was done with them. Basically, the system opened around 10-15 queues but after that it couldn't handle any more queues it seems and started to throw that error.

I also tried giving each child process its own desiredmsgtype (see the msg_get_queue() function) when sending a message and each parent message its own unique desiredmsgtype when sending a reply but that didn't work either. Either some of my messages were being lost or I started to get the error "msgsnd: Resource temporarily unavailable" when the children tried to send their messages to the parent (Note that some of the messages from the children did go through).

So for example:

child code:

```
$child_msg = (object)array('unique_msg_id' => $unique_msg_id);

if (!msg_send ($ipc_msg_queue, $child_msg_id, $child_msg, true, true, $msg_err))
{
    echo "Msg not sent because $msg_err\n";
}

$parent_msg_id = $unique_msg_id;

if (msg_receive ($ipc_msg_queue, $parent_msg_id, $msg_type, 16384, $msg, true, 0, $msg_error))
{
    echo "Msg from parent with id: $parent_msg_id";
}
```

parent code:

```
while each child process is running:

    while (msg_receive ($ipc_msg_queue, $child_msg_id, $msg_type, 16384, $msg, true, 0, $msg_error))
    {
        echo "Msg from child with id: $child_msg_id";
    }

    $parent_msg_id = $msg->unique_msg_id;
    $parent_msg = 'perform some action';

    if (!msg_send ($ipc_msg_queue, $parent_msg_id, $parent_msg, true, true, $msg_err))
    {
        echo "Msg not sent because $msg_err\n";
    }
```

I'm on a Linux box and I looked at /proc/sys/fs/mqueue/msg_max to see the limit for the maximum messages allowed in a queue but found that that file does not even exist. Could that be a reason for my problems?

So, I want to know:

How you would go about solving this problem by using message queues in php?

Why do you think I might be getting the errors that I have identified above?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Consider using an entirely different message queue system, like [Gearman](http://gearman.org/).  It's meant as a distributed work queue.  It has an extensive [PHP extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gearman.php).  Check out the [examples](https://www.php.net/manual/en/gearman.examples-reverse.php) and see if it meets your needs.  It should be a great replacement for what you're trying (unsuccessfully) to do, given your description.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm restricted to just using php so I can't use any third party framework. I need to find a solution with just php

Comment: So you can [custom-compile PHP to turn on SysV messaging](http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/sem.installation.php), but you can't install a third-party binary?  That's a very odd requirement.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know i am right here, but it think, one can always use session. (" I'm restricted to just using php so I can't use any third party framework. I need to find a solution with just php")

Answer (score 0):

If you're fork()ing new children, you're copying the parent's memory for each child.  If you create a message queue for each child as you create these forks, each child gets a copy of the message queue for all children before it.

I'm not sure if you've considered this, though you probably have.

Regards,
Paul